# UITextField clear button use with screen animation

Tags: ios, animation, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a screen that performs an animation (shifts screen up) when the user enters a text field so it stays visible when entering data then shifts back down once the user is done entering data.  The problem I am having is when the user tries to use the clear button inside the text box (set with site_TextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways).  The flow for the text fields when the clear button is pressed should be:

textFieldShouldEndEditing --> textFieldDidEndEditing --> textFieldShouldClear --> textFieldShouldBeginEditing --> textFieldDidBeginEditing

However, the textFieldDidEndEditing method is where the animation is called from and when the animation is performed the above sequence stops and textFieldShouldClear is not called.  I am hoping it is something simple I am just missing.  Any input is appreciated!

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
    NSLog(@"In textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == site_TextField || textField == phone_TextField) {
        [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"In textFieldShouldEndEditing");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == site_TextField || textField == phone_TextField) {
        [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSLog(@"In textFieldShouldClear");
    return YES;
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    if (textField != site_TextField && textField != phone_TextField) {
        return;
    }

    int movementDistance = 0;
    if (textField == site_TextField) {
        movementDistance = 100;
    } else if (textField == phone_TextField) {
        movementDistance = 170;
    }

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
                    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` has no return value?

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error, fixed the post.  That method doesn't even need to be there, I just put it in when I was debugging so trace thru the code and see what order to make sure I was following it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the first `textFieldShouldEndEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` are triggered by touch down on the clear button.  And the `textFieldShouldClear` is triggered by touch up.  But with your animation, the textField moves immediately after the touch down, so the touch up does not register.  Try using the textField `didEndOnExit` event to trigger a method which does the animation down.

Comment: This did get me close to what I wanted to do (I implemented textFieldShouldReturn from the delegate, but I believe they are both triggered by the same event).  I was also using a gesture recognizer to end editing and had to call the animate code from the target for the gesture recognizer as well.